# Twig - Get All Blocks From Template

Tags: php, twig

This is my `base.template.html`

```
{% block header %}{% endblock %}
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}{% endblock %}
```

**UPDATED**

My quetion is how can I get all blocks from `base.template.html` into array?

```
array => ['header', 'body', 'footer']
```

I know use `regex` can solve this problem, but Twig have alias function

```
block('header')
```

Comment: what do you mean "get"? In an other template? Via php?

Comment: I need to get all blocks from base template. Array or variables `header, body, footer`.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy!

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment;

/** @var $template Twig_Template */
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('base.template.html');

/** @var $blocks array */
$blocks = $template->getBlockNames();

var_dump($blocks);
```

will return array of block names:

```
['header', 'body', 'footer']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's possible for Twig to return a block array. I did find something here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/master/index.html under the parser section there's a getBlockStack() function. But not too sure how to access it.

At the moment I am using regular expression to find all the block names:

```
private function _getBlocks($str) {
    // find all block starting tags
    preg_match_all("/\{%\s+block\s+([a-zA-Z\_0-9]+)\s+%\}/", $str, $matches);

    return $matches[1];
}
```

If you find a better method, please let me know. Otherwise the function above is a quick and lightweight alternative.